# Wasserstein Metric: Question About Empirical Computation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to estimate the Wasserstein distance between two empirical distributions for which I only have two sets of data which effectively create two histograms.

I am [reading here](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Elarry/=sml/Opt.pdf) that the computation for this 1-dimensional case where we want to compute $W_p(P,Q)$ when $p=1$ then the formula is:
$$W_1(P,Q) = \sum_{i=1}^n |X_i - Y_i|$$
where we have $n$ data points and $X_i$ and $Y_i$ come from the data sets representing $P$ and $Q$ respectively.

**My question here is: isn't the order of the $X_i$ and $Y_i$ important?** I am envisioning two Gaussians with the same distribution, $P=Q \implies W_1(P,Q)=0$ but the data is the same but order is reversed: $X_i = Y_{(n+1)-i}$. This empirical estimate will be non-zero.

I am just asking here because there is no mention of the order of the data but it does seem important. I am trying to compute some of these metrics and I'm wondering if I should first sort the data somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document you link may have changed since your post but the current version states:

*If $P$ is the empirical distribution of a dataset
$X_1, \dots, X_n$ and $Q$ is the empirical distribution of another dataset $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ of the same size, then the distance takes a very simple function **of the order statistics**:*
$$W_{p}(P,Q)=\left(\sum _{i=1}^{n}\|X_{(i)}-Y_{(i)}\|^{p}\right)^{1/p}$$

So you are right, the data indeed need to be sorted before taking the differences.